# Laravel 7 Migration - Foreign Key created but its constraint code not working

Tags: mysql, laravel-7, referential-integrity

I cannot seem to figure out why my PK and FK of the same exact type are not linked in Laravel. **Both tables are InnoDB.**  The foreign key in the second screenshot shows that I can enter any integer even if if does not exist in the PK table.  Please help. My code for the FK creation migration is below:

**Proof that both PK and FK are same type (Meeting table on the left; Participant table on the right:**
[image: Proof that both PK and FK are same type]

**Proof that the Integrity Constraint can be broken ( I can enter 9999999 etc. I should only be able to enter 1, 2 or 3 as FK IDs):**
[image: Proof that the Integrity Constraint can be broken:]

**Migration file:**

```
  <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CreateParticipantsTable extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
            
            Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
    
                $table->id();
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('meeting_id')->nullable();
                $table->string('attendance');
                $table->string('invited');
    
    
                $table->foreign('meeting_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('meetings')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    
                $table->timestamps();
               // $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    
            });
        }
    
     
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('participants');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In the **/config/database.php** file you have to set the storage engine for the database **before** tables are created.  What's weird is I was changing the storage engine for the database **after** I created some other tables before and did not have any issues:

```
'engine' => null,
```

to

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```